# How to convert this raw query to Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have three models.

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64

class AccountPermission(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text_value = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    date_value = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Data(models.Model):
    regions = models.ArrayField()
    companies = models.ArrayField()
    last_updated = models.DateField()
```

I'm trying to take this sql statement

```sql
SELECT * FROM Data d 
    INNER JOIN account_permissions p0 ON p0.group_id = %s AND p0.field = 'regions' AND p0.text_value = ANY(d.regions)
    INNER JOIN account_permissions p1 ON p1.group_id = %s AND p1.field = 'companies' AND p1.text_value = ANY(d.companies)
    INNER JOIN account_permissions p2 ON p2.group_id = %s AND p2.field = 'last_updated' AND p2.date_value >= d.last_updated
```

and convert to the equivalent Django ORM code.

I've referred to Django's model expressions, however, I can't make sense of what I should be using/how to even begin. Thoughts?

Comment: That SQL query doesn't look correct anyway.

Comment: How so? I agree it's a bit strange, but it does only select the data that I've granted to the group based on the account_permissions table (which is what I want)

Comment: The `ANY( )` with just one value makes no sense.

Comment: `regions` and `companies` are arrays. From what I understand (please correct if I'm wrong :) since I'm no expert with sql) `p0.text_value = ANY(d.regions)` is equivalent basically saying "check if p0.text_value is an element in d.regions"

Comment: You may need to use SubQueries to achieve this.. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Unfortunately I haven't been active in a Django project for nearly a year, but I do have some memories of Django assigning variables for various tables it will alias to allow for multiple joins to the same table. 

Django's support has never been super great for complex joins (joining on two conditions as you have in your example) let alone performing joins against the same table using aliases.  I'm definitely interested if anyone can answer this.

Comment: That's definitely what I was initially thinking. I guess I need to just dive a bit deeper into the docs.